# Refactoring a while loop in javascript using .map or underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, underscore.js

Ok so I have this really terrible while loop in my code.  I am trying to refactor it to use Underscore.js or the .map function in js but I keep getting stuck.  here is what I have that is working code:

```
createGroupedChannels = (array) ->
        groups = []
        i = 0
        column = 0
        while i < array.length
          if groups.length <= 2
            groups.push [array[i]]
            i += 1
          else
            groups[column].push array[i]
            column += 1
            i += 1
            if column is 3
              column = 0
        groups.reverse()
```

The point is to split the array into 3 groups and maintain the initial relative order.  I have tried several configurations attempting to use underscore to no avail.  I am fairly new to JS and any help is greatly appreciated.

What I currently have with .map is not working at all but I am adding it as per the request:

```
createGroupedChannels = (array) ->
        _.map array, () ->
          i = 0
          column = 0
          groups = []
          if groups.length <= 2
            groups.push [array[i]]

          else
            groups[column].push array[i]
          i += 1
          column += 1
          column = 0 if column is 3
          groups.reverse()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried with `.map`?

Comment: I edited to show what I tried despite being a bit embarrassed

Comment: This line look suspect: `column = 0 if column is 3`. You can also do `column = column + 1 % 3` and avoid the `if` alltogether.

Comment: should have mentioned this was coffeescript so I think that is valid syntax.

Comment: I suspected as much. It looks good to me. Maybe you can glean from the output where the bug is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `Array.prototype.map`, but with `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    groups = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        r[i % 3].push(a);
        return r;
    }, [[],[],[]]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(groups, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: can you explain the last part(", [[],[],[]])") to me because my search is turning up nothing?

Comment: that is an empyt array for the return value of `reduce`. it needs three empty arrays for the sorted columns.

Comment: I understand that but I am unfamiliar with this syntax and can't find any docs on it.  Thanks again for your help.